# Query to have the table name from which data is to be selected be an expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server version 12.2.9 (i.e. SQL Server 2014, I think)?

In a SQL query, is it possible to have one or more of the table names from which data is to be selected, to be an expression that will be evaluated during query execution? For e.g. as in the following pseudo-code?

```
SELECT * 
FROM MainTable AS mainTable, 
(
  /* Expression here that returns 
     a string (or what type do we return) 
     denoting the other table name 
  */ 
) AS AliasFoo
WHERE AliasFoo.Id = mainTable.ExternalId;
```

Could you please provide a specimen of such a query? Specifically, what data type are we returning from the expression that is supposed to return a reference to the table / table name?

**FURTHER DEVELOPMENT OF THE QUESTION**

To make the example a little more concrete as to invite proper assistance, here is a contrived example.

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
ActivityType
---------
Id ( int primary key, identity )
ActivityName (possible values are 'Jogging', 'Biking', and more)

ActivityLog
--------
Id ( int, primary key, identity) 
DateTime
ActivityTypeId
ActivityDetailId (a primary key of one of the following activity detail tables)

ACTIVITY DETAIL TABLES

Jogging
--------
Id ( int, primary key, identity) 
WhoWasJogging
ForHowLong
WhatShoesWereTheyWearing

Biking
--------
Id ( int, primary key, identity) 
WhoWasBiking
WhatBikeWasThat
WhatBrand
Color
Speed
ForHowLong
```

Given the above tables, could I have a query like so?

```
SELECT aLog.DateTime, aType.ActivityName, activityDetail.*
FROM ActivityLog AS aLog, ActivityType AS aType, 
(
  /*
  if ActivityType.ActivityName == 'Jogging' then the 'Jogging' table, 
  else if ActivityType.ActivityName == 'Biking' then the 'Biking' table
  */
) AS activityDetail
WHERE aLog.ActivityTypeId = aType.Id
AND activityDetail.Id = aLog.ActivityDetailId;
```

Comment: You can construct your query as a string and use the sp_executesql to execute it. But there are pros and cons for dynamic sql. Please check [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, whether this is the best answer or not depends on how many different tables you have in the real world. So for small numbers of tables `left joining` is a possible solution as shown below. You can see this adds complexity in the select columns but this may give you want you want.

```
select aLog.[DateTime]
  , aType.ActivityName
  , case when aType.ActivityName = 'Jogging' then J.WhoWasJogging else B.WhoWasBiking end WhoWas
  -- And so on
from ActivityLog as aLog
inner join ActivityType as aType on aType.Id = aLog.ActivityTypeId
left join Jogging as J on aType.ActivityName = 'Jogging' and aLog.ActivityDetailId = J.Id
left join Biking as B on aType.ActivityName = 'Biking' and aLog.ActivityDetailId = B.Id
```

It also depends whether you would want to query more than one activity type at a time or not.

And if dynamic SQL was preferred then the following should work:

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max), @Activity varchar(128) = 'Biking';

set @Sql = 'select aLog.[DateTime]
  , aType.ActivityName
  , A.*
from ActivityLog as aLog
inner join ActivityType as aType on aType.Id = aLog.ActivityTypeId
inner join ' + @Activity + ' as A on and aLog.ActivityDetailId = A.Id
where aType.ActivityName = ''' + @Activity + '''';

exec (@sql);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just another question. That `left join` is a `left inner join` and not a `left *outer* join`, right? And for inner joins, left and right don't matter. They're just the intersection of two sets, right? So, that `left join` is really just an `inner join`, correct?

Comment: `left join` is definitely not the same as `inner join` - `inner join` requires a match on both sides of the join. The way we have done it here we'll only get a join match with one of the 2 left joins.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql

Comment: Thanks so very much. That venn diagram about joins in the Quora link explained it all in one snapshot. And thanks so much for your wonderful answer.

Comment: When using the *not dynamic* SQL, I could also include `activityDetail.*` in the column list, right? And that would show all the columns for both the biking table and the jogging table in the result set, depending on whether or not there were results from the biking / jogging tables, right?

Comment: I've put that there as `A.*`

Comment: Thank you. I could do that in the version that does *not* use the dynamic SQL as well, right? `SELECT ..., acvitityDetail.* FROM ..., LEFT JOIN (CASE WHEN aType.ActivityName = 'Jogging' then Jogging ELSE Biking) AS activityDetail ON activityDetail.Id = aLog.ActivityDetailId;`?

Comment: No because in the non dynamic version you have to join *all* the tables of interest statically, and you can't alias them to be the same thing. So you need a case statement for each column you want to pull as I've shown for 1 column. Thats why I suggested its application is limited.